# AngularJS and ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a form with AngularJS. This form is:

```
<form style="margin-top:20px;" name="newNewsForm" novalidate>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="col-md-10 form-control " name="title" type="text" data-ng-model="newNews.title" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="content">Content</label>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 form-control " name="content" rows="5" cols="30" data-ng-model="newNews.content" />
        </fieldset>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>

    </form>
```

I insert it in a ng-view:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

The strangest thing is that my source code misses the button, but if I put it between the 2 fileds he appears. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you create [Plunker](http://plnkr.co)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for posting this question. I changed:

```
<textarea class="col-md-10 form-control" name="content" rows="5" cols="30" data-ng-model="newNews.content"/>
```

To:

```
<textarea class="col-md-10 form-control" name="content" rows="5" cols="30" data-ng-model="newNews.content">
            </textarea>
```

And it worked

Comment: Mark as answered then.